# n random variables' sum equals 1 , and they belong to the same distribution and are restricted in [0,1] , what distribution do they obey?

Tags: probability, distributions

$ X_1 + X_2 + .. + X_n = 1 $

$X_i$ is drawn from same distribution and they are 
restricted to [0,1] range , what distribution do they obey?

Comment: Given X_1 , X_2< 1-X_1 and X_3< 1-X_1 -X_2 etc.  This is a chain of dependencies..

Comment: To get a sense of the scope of possible answers, note that *any* set of $n$ exchangeable variables will, when conditioned on their sum equaling some attainable constant $c \ne 0$ and then divided by $c$, will give rise to such a situation.  Thus *every* univariate distribution (except the atom at zero) gives rise to at least one such solution.

Comment: @whuber not all univariate distributions are concentrated on[0,1].

Comment: @Michael Nor did I say so.  That assumption is not needed for the construction I described.

Comment: @whuber The OPs question restricted the answer to [0, 1].

Comment: @Michael Allow me to repeat: *it doesn't matter.*  You may make any such restriction you like without changing how this construction works.  Please see the [explanation by petrelharp below](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/252250/919).

Answer (score 11):

The conditions you give don't put many constraints on the random variables, other than exchangeability.  For instance, if you let $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n$ be *any* sequence of iid positive random variables, then 
$$
  X_k = \frac{Z_k}{Z_1 + \cdots Z_n}
$$
satisfies your requirement.  If the $Z_k$ are Gamma($\alpha$,1) then you'll get the Dirichlet($\alpha,\ldots,\alpha$) mentioned in other answers.

So does $(Z_1, \ldots, Z_n)$ conditioned on $Z_1 + \cdots Z_n = 1$, as long as the conditioning makes sense (and now we can let the distribution for $Z$ put positive probability on zero, too).

Interestingly, there starts to be much nicer answers if $n=\infty$: see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3642) and associated work.

Answer (score 2):

[Dirichlet Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) (per Wikipedia) is a generalization of the Beta distribution (which satisfies your requirements, when $n=2$):

$$f(x_1,...,x_n, \alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n) = \frac{1}{B({\bf \alpha})}\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{\alpha_i-1}$$

$x_i \in (0,1)$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 1$

$\alpha_i > 0$

$B(\bf{ \alpha} )$ is the Beta function, a normalizing constant in this case

Comment: For this answer to be correct, you must have all the $\alpha_i$ equal to a common value, for otherwise the $X_i$ have *different* distributions.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to a multi-dimensional generalization of the Beta distribution. There is no one distribution that covers all such cases, but a common distribution in these scenarios is the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) of order $n$. Given a set of $n$ positive parameters $\alpha_i$, the p.d.f. of this distribution is

$$
f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \propto \prod x_i^{\alpha_i-1}
$$

Comment: For this answer to be correct, you must have all the $\alpha_i$ equal to a common value, for otherwise the $X_i$ have *different* distributions.

Comment: @whuber Yep, I did not catch this -- thanks!